# First row of SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a little trouble with a SQL query. I have a table to stores results against a date. I'd like to select all distinct results with the maximum (most recent) date. I can make this work with:

```
select distinct(r.data), max(c.committed_at) as timestamp
from results r
     inner join commits c on (r.commit_id=c.id) 
where r.repository_id=65 AND data_type='data_model'
group by data
order by timestamp DESC
```

This is good and all works.

However, I want to be able to select a *third* column, which is a hash. This hash is unique to every result row.

But when I add it in to the SELECT clause, I of course have to add it to my GROUP BY too.

```
select distinct(r.data), max(c.committed_at) as timestamp, c.hash
from results r
     inner join commits c on (r.commit_id=c.id) 
where r.repository_id=65 AND data_type='data_model'
group by data, c.hash
order by timestamp DESC
```

And this throws the query out. I no longer get distinct results (of course).

I tried an aggregate function on `hash`:

```
select distinct(r.data), max(c.long_hash), max(c.committed_at) as timestamp
from results r
    inner join commits c on (r.commit_id=c.id) 
where r.repository_id=65 AND data_type='data_model'
group by data
order by timestamp DESC
```

But then I don't get the maximum time, I get the maximum *hash*.

I feel like I just want to be able to say "find the distinct results with the maximum timestamp and then just include the hash in the result", but I can't figure out how...

Cheers,
Ben

Edit: my attempt at this with `DISTINCT ON` is:

```
select distinct on (data) data, c.committed_at as committed_at, c.long_hash
from results r 
    inner join commits c on (r.commit_id=c.id) 
where r.repository_id=65 AND data_type='complexity'
order by data, c.committed_at DESC
```

But this requires an ORDER BY on `data`, which again, throws out the ordering of my results...

Edit 2:

Executing this query gives the following result:

```
'{"status":"supported","per_method":"10.2","total":"815.2","data"<snip>...}','2017-01-04 13:25:51','4a44bccca804c28c6a5e61b36b5ebcb716d4c11f'
'{"status":"supported","per_method":"8.8","total":"649.3","data":<snip>...}','2017-01-02 23:35:11','d747e657a81c5c6da4262a5298c3071082b2af41'
'{"status":"supported","per_method":"10.7","total":"944.3","data":<snip>...}','2017-01-08 17:28:57','ff4be5fa6dc88237e7855ed1b534baee69aa8800'
```

As you can see, the `data` column is in order (according the JSONB column rules), whereas the `timestamp` column is not (it goes from Jan 4th, to Jan 2nd, to Jan 8th).

Comment: which dbms is being used, like Oracle,MySQL,Postgres,SQL Server ...

Comment: Oops! Postgres. I have tried DISTINCT ON too, but that then required an ordering by the data column, which is not what I want either...

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `distinct (a),b` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`. It is always applied to all columns in the select list

Comment: Thanks. I just want to avoid ordering by that column... is there any way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cte as
(
select r.data,c.committed_at, c.hash,timestamp, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by r.data order by c.committed_at DESC) as ranking
from results r
     inner join commits c on (r.commit_id=c.id) 
where r.repository_id=65 AND data_type='data_model' 
)
Select data,committed_at, hash 
from cte where ranking=1 order by timestamp DESC
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some fiddle as well

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Sample data wasn't provided, so couldn't add one.

Comment: This looks promising and actually works! Thanks, marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `group by` with `select distinct on`.  You just adjust the `order by`.  So:

```
select distinct on (r.data) r.*, c.*
from results r inner join
     commits c
     on r.commit_id = c.id 
where r.repository_id = 65 and
      data_type = 'data_model'
order by r.data, c.committed_at desc;
```

`distinct on` does all the work you want to do.  It returns one row for each combination of values in the `distinct on` list.  The row is the first one specified by the order by.

I think this is what you intend with `distinct(r.data)`, because `distinct` itself is not a function and you would not use parentheses with it.